# Вывод ответа ajax в блок html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, php7

Есть страница index.php с post запросом

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        status: '1',
    },
    complete: function(responce){     
    $('#resp').load(responce);
    },
    })
</script>
```

Файл test.php принимает параметры пост запроса и выводит их

```
<?php 
echo $_POST['status'];
```

В зависимости от параметров запроса, test.php выполняет некоторые действия и нужно вывести выполненный test.php в index.php в div с id 'resp'. Но почему-то ответ test.php не выводится, хотя его видно в панели разработчика Google:

[image: Скрин]

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2):

Метод **[load](https://api.jquery.com/load/)** загружает данные аяксом сервера по указанному адресу. Например `$( "#result" ).load( "test.php");` отправит запрос по адресу `test.php`, получит данные и вставит в элемент. А просто для отображения данных в элементе можно воспользоваться методом **[html](https://api.jquery.com/html/)**, т.е. `$('#resp').html(responce);`

Также есть методы:

- append
- appendTo
- prepend
- prependTo
- text

---

Также если используется `complete`, то там возвращается `jqXHR`и поэтому значение надо брать так: `responce.responseText`.  Если не хочется с этим возиться или разбираться можно использовать для начала `success` вместо `complete`

Comment: Я пробовал методы html, text,  но div “resp” не меняется, он просто остаётся пустым. А должно выводится «1» или «0», в зависимости от того, какое значение параметра “status” я укажу в “index.php”.

Comment: полный html в студию) и полный js

Comment: Я пока что только тестирую, и у меня не получается, поэтому я не вставлял данный код в проект.. То что я скинул это все что есть на данный момент. Ещё в index.php находится пустой <div id=“resp”> </div>

Comment: @Вильдан ну тогда всё понятно. complete замените на success, а `id=“resp”` замените на `id="resp">` т.к. кавычки не те

Comment: @Вильдан либо в complete используйте `responce.responseText`. потому что в complete возвращается xhr. Добавил это в ответ

Comment: Я попробовал поменять "complete" на "success", и это сработало, но если выводить просто `echo $_POST['status'];`.
Если же добавить в test.php html, например `echo '<a href="123">'.$_POST['status'].'</a>';`, то в блок <div id="resp"> снова ничего не выводится..

Comment: @Вильдан видимо потому, что стоит `dataType: json` ..... .dataType - The type of data that you're expecting back from the server (читаем доки https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)